# Choreographer Skipped x frames ! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

I dont understand why the heck this happens?
Anyone has an idea ?
I am trying to send & recieve data from PHP n dynamically append data in xml layout.
Anyone has any idea? The stuff was working well when i just sent the data to PHP using asynctask.
But when i try to  recieve and append this logcat gave me heck.

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    String emailId;
    String passwordId;
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);
        emailBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

       button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()   {             
           public void onClick(View v)  {               
            try {
               new toPHP(MainActivity.this).execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }               
           }  
         });
       }
    public void afterEffect(String str){

        TextView textV1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        textV1.setText(str);        

    }
    public void showChatList(JSONArray json){

        /*
        Document doc;
        String fileloc = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\workspace\\myWeb\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml";
        try {
            doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File(fileloc));
            //Node nR = doc.getElementById("mainR");
            removeChilds(nR);
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainR);
        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) { 
            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
                ImageView pp = new ImageView(this);
                TextView name = new TextView(this);
                TextView username = new TextView(this);
                int generatedId = generateViewId();
                pp.setId(generatedId);
                LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                new ImageLoadTask(pp).execute("http://117.99.55.83/"+c.getString("img"));
                name.setText(c.getString("name"));
                username.setText(c.getString("username"));
                LL.addView(pp);
                LL.addView(name);
                LL.addView(username);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    }
    public static void removeChilds(Node node) {
        while (node.hasChildNodes())
            node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild());
    }
    public static int generateViewId() {
        for (;;) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**toPHP**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class toPHP extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONArray>{
    final MainActivity main;

    public toPHP(MainActivity main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String email,password;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
        TextView textV1 = (TextView)main.findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar)main.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
        textV1.setText("Reaching em!!");        
    }   
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... v) {


        //main = (MainActivity)parameters[0];
        //main.afterEffect("sending...");
        emailBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = emailBox.getText().toString();
        password = passwordBox.getText().toString();            
        JSONArray json = null;
        json = getUserLoggedIn(email, password);
        //main.afterEffect("drawing");
        return json;        
     }


    public JSONArray getUserLoggedIn(String email,String password){
        JSONArray json = null;
        /*
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/testand.php");
        */
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        //if (resEntity != null) {

            //String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://117.99.55.83/resource/android/CHATS.php", pairs);



        //}     
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
        main.showChatList(json);
    }

}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
12-30 17:47:34.418: I/Choreographer(736): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-30 17:47:37.221: D/dalvikvm(736): GC_CONCURRENT freed 272K, 13% free 2757K/3168K, paused 77ms+79ms, total 303ms
```

Comment: 41 frames is not a lot. What you can do is to locate all places where you are dispatching things to happen on the main thread and load them off to another thread, such that it will not be blocked and Choreaographer complains.

Comment: @Cheesebaron how do you " locate all places where you are dispatching things to happen on the main thread and load them off to another thread" ?